# Error While Calling Code From other class in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I'm developing an Asp.net website and i decided to do it by using oop concepts.

so my first thoughts is to encapsulate my code (the whole behind code )in external class then calling it in my Aspx page to be executed .

i made a new class then i derived it from the main class to be able to access main class controls like buttons,labels etc...

when i call the method which include the code it gives me an error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

so as i think this means that my second class (derived one)
 can't access to my main class objects/controls and run code depending on it's value.

the method should executes some code depending on DropDownList but it gives this error.

i really appreciate your help !

1-The behind code for main class which in (aspx page) method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace power_CMS.Authentication
{

    public  partial class Permissions : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        //connection string 
        //db name = cms
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=.\\sqlexpress ; initial catalog=cms ; integrated security = true");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        protected void btn_grant_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { //grant permission to Members
            Cms c = new Cms();
            c.User_Role_Insert();

        }
```

2-A part of designer code for my aspx page

```
 protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList drp_user;

    /// <summary>
    /// UserDataSource control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
```

3-Here's the code for my derived class which i encapsulated my code in it:

```
    namespace power_CMS
{    

    public  class Cms :power_CMS.Authentication.Permissions
    {

        //sql connection
        public  static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=.\\sqlexpress ; initial catalog=*** ; integrated security = true");


        public void User_Role_Insert()
        {




            if (drp_user.SelectedIndex == 0 && drp_permission.SelectedIndex == 0 || drp_user.SelectedIndex == 0 || drp_permission.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                //make sure that user will make a valid choise with both dropdownlists
                //Invalid Choise Code

               lbl_confirm.Text = "Please Make A Valid Choise !";
            }

            else
            {
               // Valid Choise Code

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    // string str = "insert into aspnet_UsersInRoles(UserId,RoleId) values('"+c.drp_user.SelectedValue+"','"+drp_permission.SelectedValue+"')";

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("aspnet_UsersInRoles_Insert", conn);

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid(drp_user.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("RoleId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid(drp_permission.SelectedValue);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();

                    lbl_confirm.Text = "Permission Granted ...!";


                    drp_user.SelectedIndex = 0;
                   drp_permission.SelectedIndex = 0;

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                   lbl_confirm.Text = "Sorry <br> This User Already Have A Permission ! ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code generates the error?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code and see which object is `null`

Comment: @ekad if (drp_user.SelectedIndex == 0 && drp_permission.SelectedIndex == 0 || drp_user.SelectedIndex == 0 || drp_permission.SelectedIndex == 0) ,,, This Line which generates the error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where your **drp_use**r define ? It will be null if you not define this object

if you still want not define drp u must change in if

```
if (drp_user != null && (drp_user.SelectedIndex == 0 ....
```

Comment: it's in my main aspx webpage and this is the designer code        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList drp_user;
        
        /// <summary>
        /// UserDataSource control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>

Comment: ok this hide the error , but it didn't help , i still want to run this code depending on the dropdownlist in my main aspx page

Comment: It has been null because it not in the right context. drp_user only available in your code behind. In this case, it was placed in a different class. If you want to design it in another class, I think you must pass the dropdownbox to your function and then use it

Comment: i think this will help me , could you please write a sample code for this ?

Comment: Thanks alot @Grey_Wolf i did what you said and it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

In your aspx markup, Do you have Autopostback set to true? Why not you use dropdown selected index changed event to log the values and pass it to your DB method? In this way you can achieve this..

Comment: you didn't understand my problem ,, i have 2 classes A ,B .. Class A have controls/objects .. and B : A .

Then i wrote code in Class B to execute Code depending on objects in Class A  . 

When i call The class B method In my Class A it gives me this Error .